# Existence of PRGs satisfying the following weaker definition

Tags: provable-security, pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function

Consider the following definition.  Let $p(n) > n$ be a polynomial, and $G_n: \{0, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{p(n)}$ a PRG. Moreover, given $x \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^n$, we say $S$ is a *length $n-1$ contiguous substring of* $G(x)$ if $S = s_0\cdots s_{n-2}$ with $s_i \in \{0, 1\}$ is a contiguous substring of $G(x)$.

Then we say a PRG $G$ is *"$n-1$ subsequence secure"* if for all PPT adversaries $\mathcal{A}$, and any contiguous subsequence (substring) $S$ of $G(x)$ with $|S|=n-1$,
there exists a negligible function $\mu$ such that
$$
|Pr_{x \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^n}[\mathcal{A}(S)=1] - Pr_{r \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^{n-1}}[\mathcal{A}(r)=1]| \leq \mu(n).
$$
Do we have any PRGs that could provably satisfy this definition (unconditionally)?  I ask about provably so because this definition is strictly weaker than the standard definition of a PRG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with a primitive linear feedback shift register of length $n$, it defines a "full cycle" generator where we can take any non-zero initial fill and the state will cycle through all non-zero fills. We can augment this with an additional zero for the feedback bit in the case `1000..000` and define the feedback back for the `000...000` state to be one and then cycle through all states. The set of all possible fills would then give a uniform distribution on all possible substrings and would satisfy the criterion with $\mu=0$

It would however be a rubbish PRNG.